# Need regex to compress html but exclude pre, textarea and script tags PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, compression

I tested several small regexs to compress html and they all basically do a great job

```
$reg = array(
    '/^\n+|^[\t\s]*\n+/m',
    '/\s\s+/',
    '/\r|\n/isU',
    '/\t/isU'
);
$rep = array(
    '',
    ' ',
    ' ',
    ' '
);
----------------------
$reg = array(
    '/\n/',         // replace end of line by a space
    '/\>[^\S ]+/s',     // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
    '/[^\S ]+\</s',     // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
    '/(\s)+/s'      // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
);
$rep = array(
' ',
'>',
'<',
'\\1'
);
------------------------------
$reg ='/\s\s+/';
$rep =" ";
----------------------
$reg = "/(\n\r|\r\n|\n|\r|\t| {2})/";
$rep ="";

$new_content = preg_replace($reg, $rep, $content);
```

But I need one that would exclude pre and script tag contents from the compression.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using regex for this, and not an HTML parser?

Comment: let the server do it (gzip)